Ternary Table Relationships in SQLAlchemy ORM
I'm trying to figure out how to do a "ternary" table relationship, which is many-many-many. I've found online how to model this as an ERD, but I'm having difficulty modeling this in SQLAlchemy's DeclarativeBase approach.
Here's an ERD of what i'm trying to accomplish:
Screenshot of ERD with tables
And here's the Python table code I'm trying to get working:
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)

workers_queues_table = Table(
    "workers_queues",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("fk_worker_id", ForeignKey("workers.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("fk_queue_id", ForeignKey("queues.id"), primary_key=True),
)

profiles_workers_queues_table = Table(
    "profiles_workers_queues",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("fk_profile_id", ForeignKey("profiles.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("fk_workers_queues_worker_id", ForeignKey("workers_queues.fk_worker_id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("fk_workers_queues_queue_id", ForeignKey("workers_queues.fk_queue_id"), primary_key=True),
    UniqueConstraint("fk_workers_queues_worker_id", "fk_workers_queues_queue_id"),
)

class Queue(Base):
    __tablename__ = "queues"
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text)

    workers: Mapped[list["Worker"]] = relationship(
        secondary=workers_queues_table,
        back_populates="queues",
    )
    profiles: Mapped[list["Profile"]] = relationship(
        secondary=workers_queues_table,
        back_populates=""
    )

class Worker(Base):
    __tablename__ = "workers"
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint("name", "hostname")
    )
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=False)

    profiles: Mapped[list["Profile"]] = relationship()
    queues: Mapped[list["Queue"]] = relationship()

class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = "profiles"
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text)

    workers: Mapped[list["Worker"]] = relationship()
    queues: Mapped[list["Queue"]] = relationship()

I don't know how to fill in the relationship() bits in the class models, especially back_populates since that would be expecting an attribute in another model, not a Table entity (i assume?).
Is this possible in the ORM?
Thanks!
